# Two cardview created, when trying to update the cardview

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to design a page where address are stored in recycler view -> cardview.

When the user clicks the add address button from the Activity A the user is navigated to the add address page in Activity B. Here the user can input customer name, address line 1 and address line two.

Similarly, When the user clicks the edit address button from the Activity A**(data in activity A is passed to activity B)** the user is navigated to the edit address page in Activity B. Here the user can input customer name, address line 1 and address line two, city, state and pincode.

And once save button is clicked in Activity B, existing cardview should be updated with new information in Activity A.

**This design is just like the amazon mobile app add address option.**

**Example:** If the user has multiple address(A,B and C) and clicks edit button in Address B cardview. Then user is navigated to Activity B for editing the address and once save button is clicked the Address B cardview should be updated with the latest information.

**Actual result as of now:** A new cardview is created with the updated information instead of updating in the existing cardview.

Code in Activity A: **I'm making use of the same onActivityResult() for both addAddress and editAddress**

```
public class ProfileManageAdressFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter> reviews;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        Button addAddress;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_profile_manage_adress);
        addAddress = findViewById(R.id.addNewAddress);
        addAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this, AddNewAddress.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.addressRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode;
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            customer_name = data.getStringExtra("customer_name");
            address_one = data.getStringExtra("address_one");
            address_two = data.getStringExtra("address_two");
            city = data.getStringExtra("city");
            state = data.getStringExtra("state");
            pincode = data.getStringExtra("pincode");

            reviews.add(new ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter(customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode));
            adapter = new ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this, reviews);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //saveData(customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode);

        } else if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            customer_name = data.getStringExtra("customer_name");
            address_one = data.getStringExtra("address_one");
            address_two = data.getStringExtra("address_two");
            city = data.getStringExtra("city");
            state = data.getStringExtra("state");
            pincode = data.getStringExtra("pincode");
            
            reviews.add(new ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter(customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode));
            adapter = new ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this, reviews);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in RecyclerAdapter:**

```
public class ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    private String sCustomer_name, sAddress_one, sAddress_two, sCity, sState, sPincode;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode;
        private Button edit, remove;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            customer_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.customerName);
            address_one = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.addressLineOne);
            address_two = v.findViewById(R.id.addressLineTwo);
            city = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardCity);
            state = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardState);
            pincode = v.findViewById(R.id.cardPincode);
            edit = v.findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
            remove = v.findViewById(R.id.removeAddress);
        }
    }

    public ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter(ProfileManageAdressFragment profileManageAdressFragment, ArrayList<ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter> dataset) {
        mDataset.clear();
        mDataset.addAll(dataset);
    }

    @Override
    public ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_manage_address, parent, false);
        final ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter profileManageAddressGetterSetter = mDataset.get(position);
        holder.address_one.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getAddress_line_1());
        holder.address_two.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getGetAddress_line_2());
        holder.customer_name.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getContractor_name());
        holder.city.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getCity());
        holder.state.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getState());
        holder.pincode.setText(profileManageAddressGetterSetter.getPincode());

        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditNewAddress.class);
                switch (holder.getAdapterPosition()) {

                    case 0:
                        mDataset.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), mDataset.size());

                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("*********" + holder.address_one.getText());

                        sCustomer_name = holder.customer_name.getText().toString();
                        sAddress_one = holder.address_one.getText().toString();
                        sAddress_two = holder.address_two.getText().toString();
                        sCity = holder.city.getText().toString();
                        sState = holder.state.getText().toString();
                        sPincode = holder.pincode.getText().toString();

                        intent.putExtra("customer_name", sCustomer_name);
                        intent.putExtra("address_one", sAddress_one);
                        intent.putExtra("address_two", sAddress_two);
                        intent.putExtra("city", sCity);
                        intent.putExtra("state", sState);
                        intent.putExtra("pincode", sPincode);

                        ((Activity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("*********" + holder.address_one.getText());

                        sCustomer_name = holder.customer_name.getText().toString();
                        sAddress_one = holder.address_one.getText().toString();
                        sAddress_two = holder.address_two.getText().toString();
                        sCity = holder.city.getText().toString();
                        sState = holder.state.getText().toString();
                        sPincode = holder.pincode.getText().toString();


                        intent.putExtra("customer_name", sCustomer_name);
                        intent.putExtra("address_one", sAddress_one);
                        intent.putExtra("address_two", sAddress_two);
                        intent.putExtra("city", sCity);
                        intent.putExtra("state", sState);
                        intent.putExtra("pincode", sPincode);
                        ((Activity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDataset.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), mDataset.size());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

**Code in Activity B:**

```
public class EditNewAddress extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode;
    private Button add_address;
    private String sCustomer_name, sAddress_one, sAddress_two, sCity, sState, sPincode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_address);

        customer_name = findViewById(R.id.customerName);
        address_one = findViewById(R.id.addressOne);
        address_two = findViewById(R.id.addressTwo);
        add_address = findViewById(R.id.addAddress);
        city = findViewById(R.id.city);
        state = findViewById(R.id.state);
        pincode = findViewById(R.id.pincode);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        sCustomer_name = intent.getStringExtra("customer_name");
        sAddress_one = intent.getStringExtra("address_one");
        sAddress_two = intent.getStringExtra("address_two");
        sCity = intent.getStringExtra("city");
        sState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
        sPincode = intent.getStringExtra("pincode");

        customer_name.setText(sCustomer_name);
        address_one.setText(sAddress_one);
        address_two.setText(sAddress_two);
        city.setText(sCity);
        state.setText(sState);
        pincode.setText(sPincode);

        add_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(customer_name.getText().toString().equals("") || address_one.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        address_two.getText().toString().equals("") || city.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        state.getText().toString().equals("") || pincode.getText().toString().equals("")
                        ) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditNewAddress.this, "Please input all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    sCustomer_name = customer_name.getText().toString();
                    sAddress_one = address_one.getText().toString();
                    sAddress_two = address_two.getText().toString();
                    sCity = city.getText().toString();
                    sState = state.getText().toString();
                    sPincode = pincode.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(EditNewAddress.this, ProfileManageAdressFragment.class);
                    intent.putExtra("customer_name", sCustomer_name);
                    intent.putExtra("address_one", sAddress_one);
                    intent.putExtra("address_two", sAddress_two);
                    intent.putExtra("city", sCity);
                    intent.putExtra("state", sState);
                    intent.putExtra("pincode", sPincode);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm new to android and kindly help me solve this. Million thanks in advance for solutions! :)

Comment: Are you storing the address somewhere like SharedPrefs?

Comment: I'm planning to use a room databse instead of the shared preference. But as of now, only  concern is that when I edit the cardview(update) a new card is being created instead of a  modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the same mistake again.

Reinitializing List and adapter every time in onActivityResult, so every time your data length 1 because the list is Reinitialize and add new data.

**For your current situation**

You can not edit already added list data. so you need to do 2 things pass cardView or list position to activity 2 and after successfully editing pass position to activity 1 again. so now you have a position. In onActivityResult removeData from list using position Like `list.remove(position);` and after removing add data to that position like. `list.add(position,data);`

Comment: I've initialised the list in onCreate only. And if i don't call set the adapter in the  onActivityResult in my case the cardview itself is not getting created. Now with the above code a cardview is created one below the other. In case like you said if it is reinitialised it wont create a cardview one below the other and it will simply override the existing one.

Comment: Anyways list.remove(position); and list.add(position,data); is the one that i was going through last nitght. I'll try it and post the answer.

Comment: @SapthagiriManivannan  Init this thing in your onCreate and call on adapter.notifyDataSetChange in onResult. If you alredy done then please update your questiuon with new codesnippet reviews.add(new ProfileManageAddressGetterSetter(customer_name, address_one, address_two, city, state, pincode));
            adapter = new ProfileManageAddressRecyclerAdapter(ProfileManageAdressFragment.this, reviews);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Hey Bro, @deepakgupta7403 Kindly look into the question in this link and see whether you have an answer. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876824/how-to-read-a-file-from-internal-storage-or-external-storage-and-store-the-file