# How to read a file from internal storage or external storage and store the file in a arrayList in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-permissions, android-file

My requirement is the end-user must be able to upload files into the application from internal or external storage and finally display the name of the file in the page.

**Actual result:** Now I've fetched the file name from the storage and displayed the name in my page.

**Expected Result:** The end user must be able to load image or video files from external or internal storage to the application and finally display their name in the page.

But don't have any idea about how to load read the file from storage and store it in a arrayList.

**Code for fetching the file name**

```
public class ServiceDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private Button next, attachment_one;
    private ImageButton attach_file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_details);

        next = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        attachment_one = findViewById(R.id.attachmentOne);
        attach_file = findViewById(R.id.attachFile);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceDetails.this, ServiceAddress.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        attach_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 10001);
                }
                new MaterialFilePicker()
                        .withActivity(ServiceDetails.this)
                        .withRequestCode(1)
                        .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.(mkv|wmv|avi|mpeg|swf|mov|mp4|jpg|jpeg)$"))
                        .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
                        .start();
            }
        });

        attachment_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attachment_one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String file_path = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
            String file_array[] = file_path.split("/");
            String file_name = file_array[file_array.length - 1];
            // Do anything with file

            if(attachment_one.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                attachment_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                attachment_one.setText(file_name);
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10001: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(ServiceDetails.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(ServiceDetails.this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to android and kindly help me providing solution for this answer. Million thanks in advance!

Image showing file attachment option[image]

Comment: You can remove all the posted code as it is irrelevant how you obtained a file system path. Enough would be you told you had a full path to a text file. Tell what the path is.

Comment: Got your point partially and didn't understand this part "Enough would be you told you had a full path to a text file" but just want to make sure that everyone is aware of the code and can provide solution to the existing code easily. Also I would get some suggestions from some experienced engineers also to change my coding style like in my previous questions.

Comment: I want the file to be be loaded to an arrayList from internal or external storage.

Comment: @blackapps do you have any suggestions for this question?

Comment: `The end user must be able to load image or video files from external or internal storage to the application` AND `idea about how to load read the file from storage and store it in a arrayList.` It is pretty unclear what you want to load in an array list once the user has selected a file.

Comment: @blackapps I want the file itself to be loaded into the arraylist. The reason - In real scenario: The user can upload image and video files into the app. Later if the User wants to remove the file then the user can remove by clicking the delete button. Technically, If the user adds 5 files. I want to store those files into the arraylist. And later if the user click the cross button on random file. For example: File 2, then i'll code to remove the second position in array list. I'm new to android. If my approach is wrong please suggest me good solutions. Thanks very much!

Comment: You again speak from loading or storing a file in an arraylist. But i think you wanna only put file names in that list.

Comment: @blackapps My goal - Whenever a user uploads a file in the application in real time.  The file name should appear in the page like the image updated above and the fetched file should be loaded into the arrayList. The user should also be able to delete the uploaded file. For this scenario. Kindly suggest what approach I should follow. I'm thinking of storing the file in the array and later if the user deletes then the code will remove the file from the array. Is it then possible to remove a file only with its name?. I only want the file names to appear in screen and not in arrayList.

Comment: `The file name should appear in the page `. Ok. I understand that a page can display a name. `the fetched file should be loaded into the arrayList.`. Sorry, but i have no idea how you would load a pdf file or a video or a word document in an arraylist. And how would that look like? I still think you only wanna store a file name in that list.

Comment: File name/path/uri.

Comment: @blackapps Please look into image attached above. This is how the file name will look when the user uploads a file into the application. And this is process of fetching the file name and displaying is completed.

Comment: @blackapps Now my expectation is to load the file into some placeholder like arraylist(Suggest me some other idea if any) so that i can manage the file later. And if the user wishes to delete the uploaded file then the file must be removed from the list.

Comment: You keep telling that you load files in an array list and i told you twice or more times that i have no idea how that would look like. I also tell you for the fourth time now that file names/paths/uries can very well be added to a string arraylist.

Comment: In your posted image i do not see file names. And i have no idea what the image would ecpress.

Comment: @blackapps file names/paths/uries can very well be added to a string arraylist. Thanks for this information. So this is the suggestion I was expecting. I didn't just exactly want to do what i said(Store a file in arrayList). Instead i wanted suggestions on how i can manage the file(add and remove) by having the names/paths/uries in the arrayList.

Comment: @blackapps In real scenario, if a user uploads a file into the app and lets say 5 files. Once after uploading the files. And finally the user wants to delete the third file. And once after that the user wants to save it. And this is my scenario. Can you tell me how to proceed. I'm literally new to android and don't have any idea how i would tackle this scenario.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be possible to store a whole file in arrayList(It might be impossible also). kindly correct and suggest me solution if any. Thanks very much for taking time and replying back. :)

Comment: You want the user to delete the third file. That should be possible depending on how the file was choosed. And then you want to save it. It is pretty unclear what you wanna save.

Comment: I want to save the user uploaded files in the backend database @blackapps

Comment: So whatever files that the user uploads into the application should be saved to some place holder. In code I should be able to remove the file which was uploaded and finally when the user clicks the save button then the files must be saved to the database. I'm just searching for a way to save the files in someplaceholder that's all

Answer (score 0):

As you are willing to load the title of video/images, and other file related information from the External Storage. You have to use this code and also make sure don't forget to create a Arraylist with model(required to extract information and find to the listview).

```
        //ContentResolver and contentProvider as well as cursor
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
        };
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionargs = null;
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " Desc";
        Uri content_uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(content_uri, projection, selection, selectionargs, orderBy);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
        }
        while (true) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
            Uri VideoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
            Log.d("uri", "onCreate: video path " + VideoUri);
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
            float size = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
//          loading  a thumbnail from the content resolver
            // Load thumbnail of a specific media item.
            Bitmap thumbnail = null;
            try {
                thumbnail = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(VideoUri, new Size(200, 200), null);
                Log.d("thumbnail", "onCreate: Lodaing a thumbnail");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("thumbnail", "onCreate: Showing Error on thumbnail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            videolist.add(new Video(thumbnail, VideoUri, title, size));
            if (!cursor.isLast()) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            } else {
                Log.d("lastItem", "onCreate: last uri is encountered");
                break;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```